# Find image of $T$ in the $xy$ plane under the following transformation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, coordinate-systems

$T$ is the triangle formed by (0,0),(1,0) and (0,2) in the $uv$ plane. The transformation is defined by $x= 2u+v ,y=u^2−v$.

I'm completely lost. I've been trying to write $u$ and $v$ as a function of $x$ and $y$ but I can't do it.

I've been able to figure out that the triangle in the $uv$ plane is defined by $u>0, 2 \ge v + 2u$ and thus $0 \le x \le 2$. However I can't complete the exercise. The answer is what I've got and $-x \le y \le (\frac x 2)^2$

Comment: Why do you need to invert the map? Just parameterize each side of the triangle (they’re line segments, so this should be easy) and apply the transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the $\triangle AOB$ be such that $A(1,0), B(0,2)$ and $O(0,0)$.

Parametric representation of the line segment $OA$ is given by $u=t$ and $v=0$ with $0 \leq t \leq 1$. So the image of this segment under the given transformation is given by:
\begin{align*}
x & = 2t+0=2t\\
y&=t^2-0=t^2.
\end{align*}
This means the line segment $OA$ is mapped to the curve $y=\frac{x^2}{4}$, where $0 \leq x \leq 2$.

Parametric representation of the line segment $OB$ is given by $u=0$ and $v=s$ with $0 \leq s \leq 2$. So the image of this segment under the given transformation is given by:
\begin{align*}
x & = s\\
y&=-s.
\end{align*}
This means the line segment $OA$ is mapped to the line $y=-x$, where $0 \leq x \leq 2$.

Parametric representation of the line segment $BA$ is given by $u=c$ and $v=2-2c$ with $0 \leq c \leq 1$. So the image of this segment under the given transformation is given by:
\begin{align*}
x & =2\\
y&=c^2+2c-2.
\end{align*}
This means the line segment $OA$ is mapped to the vertical line $x=2$, where $-2 \leq y \leq 1$.

Thus the $\triangle AOB$ will be mapped to the region $A'OB'$, which is given by $-x \leq y \leq \frac{x^2}{4}$, where $0 \leq x\leq 2$.

Here is a image that will help you.

[image]
$\longrightarrow $
[image]